# The command mkvirtualenv does not seem to work?

Tags: python, terminal, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to create a virtual environment, but when I input the mkvirtualenv command this happens

```
PS C:\Users\jorel\Documents> mkvirtualenv '.\Trading Bot\
```

```
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
usage: virtualenv [--version] [--with-traceback] [-v | -q] [--read-only-app-data] [--app-data APP_DATA] [--reset-app-data] [--upgrade-embed-wheels] [--discovery {builtin}] [-p py] [--try-first-with py_exe]
                  [--creator {builtin,cpython3-win,venv}] [--seeder {app-data,pip}] [--no-seed] [--activators comma_sep_list] [--clear] [--no-vcs-ignore] [--system-site-packages] [--copies] [--no-download | --download]
                  [--extra-search-dir d [d ...]] [--pip version] [--setuptools version] [--wheel version] [--no-pip] [--no-setuptools] [--no-wheel] [--no-periodic-update] [--symlink-app-data] [--prompt prompt] [-h]
                  dest
virtualenv: error: unrecognized arguments: Bot"
SystemExit: 2
```

I was expecting something like this

```
(Trading Bot) PS C:\Users\jorel\Documents>
```

Comment: Make sure you have python installed

Answer (score 0):

**Put your folder name inside double quotes like "Trading Bot"**

Use 'Command Prompt' aka CMD instead Powershell

First make sure you have python installed

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
```

Then

```
mkvirtualenv "Trading Bot"
```

Result

```
(Trading Bot) C:\Apps\PPython 3.8>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try :

```bash
python -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

I create my virtual environment like this

Comment: Is the second venv the folder you would like the virtual environment in?